# If $\frac{\cos(\alpha+\gamma)}{\cos(\alpha-\gamma)} = \cos(2\beta)$, then prove that $\tan(\alpha)$, $\tan(\beta)$ and $\tan(\gamma)$ are in G.P.

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\frac{\cos(\alpha+\gamma)}{\cos(\alpha-\gamma)} = \cos(2\beta)$, then prove that $\tan(\alpha)$, $\tan(\beta)$ and $\tan(\gamma)$ are in G.P.

Comment: $\tan$, what ?  Do you mean $\tan(\alpha), \tan(\beta), \tan(\gamma)$ are in AP ?

Comment: They are in G.P. not A.P

Comment: Use geometric mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand $\frac{\cos(\alpha + \gamma)}{\cos(\alpha - \gamma)}$ as
$$ \frac{\cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)}{\cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)+\sin(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)}$$
Now by Componendo-Dividendo,
$$ \frac{\cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)}{\sin(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)}=\frac{1+\cos(2\beta)}{1-\cos(2\beta)}$$
We know that,(Use C.D. after expanding $\cos(2\beta)$ as $\cos(\beta)^2-\sin(\beta)^2$)
$$ \frac{1+\cos(2\beta)}{1-\cos(2\beta)} = \frac{1}{\tan(\beta)^2}$$
Dividing the numerator and denominator on the LHS by $ \cos(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)$,
We get,
$$ \frac{\cot(\gamma)}{\tan(\alpha)} = \frac{1}{\tan(\beta)^2}$$
QED

Answer (score 1):

$${\cos(\gamma + \alpha)\over \cos(\gamma - \alpha)} = {1 - \tan^2(\beta)\over 1 + \tan^2(\beta)}$$

By solving for $\tan(\beta)$

$$\Rightarrow \tan(\beta) = \sqrt{{-2\sin(\gamma)\sin(\alpha)\over -2\cos(\gamma)\cos(\alpha)}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \tan(\beta) = \sqrt{\tan(\alpha) \tan(\gamma)}$$

Thus $\tan(\alpha), \tan(\beta)$ and $\tan(\gamma)$ are in  GP.